# going nuts trying to write a simple function that operates on one column of a dataframe

Tags: r, function, dataframe, user-defined-functions, plyr

I am trying to write a function that "variabilizes" the ddply call:

```
december <- ddply(adk47, .(PeakName, Elevation), summarize, 
  needThese=if(sum(dec) == 0) "needThis" 
  else character(0), .progress='text')
```

Where there are 3 letter column names for each month in the df. I am trying to write the function as:

```
need.fr.month <- function(df, monthCol) {
    needThese <- ddply(df, .(PeakName, Elevation), 
                       summarize, 
                       needThese=if(sum(monthCol) == 0)
                           "needThis" else character(0)
    )
    return(needThese)
}
```

but when I call this with

```
need.fr.month(adk47, oct)
```

or with

```
need.fr.month(adk47, "oct")
```

I get the these error messages:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'monthCol' not found

or

> Error in sum("monthCol") : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

I know that I am not getting something very basic, but I don't know what.

I am using this DF to practice writing R functions. My other functions have gone fairly well; however, this is the first function in which I am trying to variabilize a df column.

Help would be gratefully appreciated.

Here is a Reproduceable Example for a subset of the data

```
PeakName    Elevation   jul aug sep oct nov dec
Algonquin   5114    0   0   1   0   0   0
Algonquin   5114    0   0   0   0   0   0
Algonquin   5114    0   0   0   1   0   0
Algonquin   5114    1   0   0   0   0   0
Allen   4340    0   0   0   0   0   0
Allen   4340    0   0   0   0   0   0
Allen   4340    0   0   1   0   0   0
Allen   4340    1   0   0   0   0   0
Allen   4340    0   0   0   0   1   0
Armstrong   4400    0   0   0   0   0   0
Armstrong   4400    0   0   0   0   0   0
Armstrong   4400    0   0   0   0   0   0
Armstrong   4400    0   0   0   0   0   0
Armstrong   4400    0   0   0   0   1   0
Armstrong   4400    0   0   0   0   0   0
Armstrong   4400    0   0   0   1   0   0
Basin   4827    1   0   0   0   0   0
Basin   4827    0   0   0   0   0   0
Basin   4827    0   0   0   0   0   0
Basin   4827    0   0   0   0   0   0
Basin   4827    0   0   0   0   0   0
Basin   4827    0   0   0   0   0   0
Basin   4827    0   0   0   0   1   0
Big.Slide   4240    0   0   0   0   0   0
Big.Slide   4240    0   0   0   1   0   0
Big.Slide   4240    0   0   0   0   0   0
Big.Slide   4240    0   0   1   0   0   0
Big.Slide   4240    0   0   0   0   0   0
Big.Slide   4240    0   0   0   0   0   0
Big.Slide   4240    0   0   0   0   0   0
Big.Slide   4240    1   0   0   0   0   0
```

I hope this suffices. Clearly this is a subset of the data. The form is that each "hike" has one line with the months columns (here truncated to July thru December) indicating a "1" for one month and a zero for the other 11.

Thanks

Wayne

Comment: Hello! [Please provide a reproducible example.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) Doing so will make your question easier to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call

```
need.fr.month(adk47, oct)
```

R looks for a variable named `oct` in your general environment, and finds nothing. Therefore it reports that it is not found.

If you call:

```
need.fr.month(adk47, "oct")
```

R attempts to use the string `"oct"` in place of `monthCol`. But taking the `sum` of a character string doesn't make sense, so it throws an error.

Passing arguments into inner functions can be difficult. A quick kludge is by the infamous eval-parse construct. While it gets the job done, it's [generally not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse) because there are often simpler methods to do the same job.

```
need.fr.month <- function(df, monthCol) {
    needThese <- eval(parse(text=paste0("ddply(df, .(PeakName, Elevation), 
                       summarize, 
                       needThese=if(sum(", monthCol, ") == 0)
                           "needThis" else character(0)
                 ")))
    )
    return(needThese)
}
```

Here, you don't need to eval-parse to get what you want. Just don't use `summarize` and rely on the base R extraction functions:

```
need.fr.month <- function(df, monthCol) {
    needThese <- ddply(df, .(PeakName, Elevation), 
                       function(x) sum(x[[monthCol]]))
    return(needThese)
    #return(needThese[needThese[["V1"]] != 0,])
}
```

I think this approach could be made better, but I can't improve on it further without knowing what you want to do with the information. If you want to find the rows that you'd like to subset, I think it would be better to do something like:

```
need.fr.month <- function(df, monthCol) {
ave(df[[monthCol]],df[["PeakName"]],df[["Elevation"]],FUN=sum)
}
adk47$need <- need.fr.month(adk47,"dec") == 0
```

This then gives you a column in your data frame that will let you subset for the data you are looking for, via `adk47$need == TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks Blue Magister, that is pretty much what I was trying to do. I modified you 2nd example a bit: 
    need.fr.month <- function(df, monthCol) {
    needThese <- ddply(df, .(PeakName, Elevation),
                       function(x) sum(x[[monthCol]]))
    subsetNeedThese <- subset(needThese, V1 == 0, select=c(PeakName, Elevation))
}

Answer (score 2):

As it seems, `summarize` cannot find objects from the environment that calls `ddply`. However, you can manually attach this environment to the search path. After the `ddply` call, you can detach the environment.

Here a quick example - a similar approach should work for you as well.

```
test_fun=function(team_vec)
{
    attach(environment())
    tmp=ddply(baseball,
              "team",
              summarise,
              duration=(if (unique(team)%in%team_vec) max(year)-min(year) else 0)
             )
    detach(environment())
    tmp
}

test_fun(c("PIT","PHI"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all, both of these are very useful.

I went with a modified version of Blue Magister's 2nd example:

```
need.fr.month <- function(df, monthCol) {
needThese <- ddply(df, .(PeakName, Elevation),
                   function(x) sum(x[[monthCol]]))
subsetNeedThese <- subset(needThese, V1 == 0, select=c(PeakName, Elevation))
```

}

as it returns exactly what I need and I understand what it is doing. I haven't dealt with attaching and detaching environments before, so I thank croy111 for the example. I will need to read up on this! Likewise, Blue Magister's eval-parse does seem like an easy way for me to do something I really don't understand properly.

I appreciated Blue Magister's comment: "Passing arguments into inner functions can be difficult". I will accept, for now, that this problem goes away if you avoid calling an inner function (such as "summarize") and think about it again next time I run into a problem like this!!

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be far easier to create  a column for which your indicator variables would be indicator variables  (as describie [Optimization: splitting dataframe into a list of dataframes, transforming data per row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934193/))  and then subset from that.

I would advocate using `data.table` not `ddply + summarize` for efficiency (but perhaps this is a longer term goal)

Using `data.table` to access `set`  (which will work on data.frames)

```
library(data.table)
adk47$monthCol <- character(nrow(adk47))
# data.table specific
# adk47 <- data.table(adk47)
# adk47[, monthCol := character(nrow(adk47))]

# find which columns are == 1
whiches <- lapply(adk47[c("jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec")],
                  function(x) which(x==1))
# data.table approach would require 
#  adk47[c("jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"),with = TRUE]

for(val in names(whiches)){ 
  set(adk47, i = whiches[[val]], j = 'monthCol', value = val)
  }

head(adk47)


       PeakName Elevation jul aug sep oct nov dec monthCol
1 Algonquin      5114   0   0   1   0   0   0      sep
2 Algonquin      5114   0   0   0   0   0   0         
3 Algonquin      5114   0   0   0   1   0   0      oct
4 Algonquin      5114   1   0   0   0   0   0      jul
5     Allen      4340   0   0   0   0   0   0         
6     Allen      4340   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

You can then subset using `monthCol`